# регулярные выражения пробелы

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

```
re.findall(r'\d*\s','550 дмитрий, 123 0leg, 412 Lera')
#['550 ', ' ', '123 ', ' ', '412 ']
```

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как поменять регулярку чтобы убрать пробелы из возврата ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, так:

```
re.findall(r'(\d+)\s','550 дмитрий, 123 0leg, 412 Lera')
# ['550', '123', '412']
```

- количество цифр должно быть не от нуля, а от 1 `*` -> `+`
- в группу берём только цифры, а пробел не берём -> `(...)...`